# ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = 4

Tags: android, google-plus

Here I am doing Google+ integartion. I am using the following code but I am facing the error which is : `onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = 4`. So please anybody help me and tell me what I am doing wrong in this code and provide me the solution for this. I will be very thankful to you. I searched a lot but found nothing. I am using the quick sample of Google plus.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android you get error code = 4, if you have not configured consent screen correctly.

```
If you are seeing ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = 4 when trying to connect, ensure that the consent screen is configured and saved.
```

Comment: In my case, I had configured consent screen correctly. i.e. I had provided all the necessary information and skipped the optional info. But it still didn't work. I had to fiddle around a bit more with consent screen and add more information like my google plus profile page etc to get it to work. Weird I know, but might help someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got the same error, but the consent screen was good for me, my real problem was a mistake with the package name when I was trying to create a new Client ID, I put the correct one, and now I can work prefectly.
Even though google says:[Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android#troubleshooting)